# Vue Js - How to format HTTP html response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a WordPress website. I am tring to get a specific post by id. Now, its showing content successfully but it's showing html tag on the main output. Like this :

[image]

**Vue JS code:**

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
        <h1>Single Post Page</h1>        
        <div v-if="postLoaded">
            {{ post.content.rendered }}
        </div>
        <p v-else>
            Please wait ...
        </p>        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            postLoaded : false, 
            post : null,
        }
    },  
    mounted() {
        let postId = this.$route.params.id;
        axios.get('https://amarcourse.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + postId )
            .then((response) => {
                this.post = response.data;
                this.postLoaded = true;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            .finally(() => {

            });
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="">
    
</style>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html But beware this will introduce dangerous security holes, if used with untrusted HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `v-html` directive, it should render content correctly as a HTML:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Single Post Page</h1>        
    <div v-if="postLoaded" v-html="post.content.rendered"></div>
    <p v-else>Please wait ...</p>        
  </div>
</template>
```